# Xcode 6 'Parse Issue, Expected a Type' using cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parsing

Since upgrading to the latest xcode, I'm having issues with certain pods where if I install them and go to import them in my code, the actual pod itself is getting labelled with "Parse Issue, Expected a Type"

I'm hoping someone can help me and tell me if they have either experienced this problem themselves, or if it's a known issues etc. I have attach images of the import in my viewcontrollers, and the error messages from xcode. For this particular example, I create a brand new UIViewControllerClass, and import the classes listed, and then set 2 extra protocols. There is nothing changed in the .m file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ABPadLockScreenViewController.h"
#import "ABPadLockScreenSetupViewController.h"


@interface ChangePinViewController : UIViewController <ABPadLockScreenViewControllerDelegate, ABPadLockScreenSetupViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

[image]

Comment: So the pod builds, but there is an error in your code when including their header. What does your .pch look like?

Comment: Nothing special in there '#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif
'

Comment: Do you get any warnings when you run `pod install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with xcode. Updating to a later version resolved the issue.